# Differencial Function

Tags: calculus

We have the function $y=50-x^2$.
We are asked to calculate through a differential function, the change that $y$ will undergo when $x$ increases from $2$ to $4$.

What I did was to calculate $y'(x) =-2x$ thus $y'(2)=-4$ and then:
$dy=y'(2)(4-2)=-4\cdot(4-2)=-8$

So the answer is that through the differential of the function we found that finally $y$ decreases by $8$, when $x$ increases from $2$ to $4$. Is my way of thinking correct?

I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $y_1 = 50-x_1^2,\ y_2 = 50-x_2^2\Rightarrow y_2-y_1 = -(x_2^2-x_1^2) = -12$

Comment: Thank you very much Hanul! Is it correct to use the derivative of the function, as We are mainly asked to use  the expression dy=y'(x) *dx?Thank you very much in advance.